# Android SDK sources : Source code does not match bytecode

Tags: java, android, android-studio

SDK versions:
compile SDK version : 27
target SDK version : 27
min SDK version : 23
Samsung tablet SDK version : 25 (Android 7.1.1)

I have sources installed for SDK version 25 and 27, but when stepping into SDK code I get an error "Byte code doesn't match source code". The source file opened is for SDK version 25.

This only happens for some android modules (android.widget, android.app) while others work fine (android.os).

The app source also contains some legacy and deprecated features.

Is there a way to
a) Find out what causes the mismatch or
b) Switch to decompiled source code

Comment: put you both gradle file, and gradle.properties also

Answer (score 0):

Its better to restart your android studio and make a clean fixed it for me